# how to change size without refreshing page after delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am using ajax to delete comments.This is workinf fine but when i delete comments comment size is not getting updated without refreshing page.I amnot getting what should i write to update comments count without refreshing page:

Following is my code for sidebar.html.haml where i am showing comments count:

```
%li.link_li
    #commentsize
      = link_to "<span>#{@current_user.comments.size}</span>Comments".html_safe, "#", :class => "nav-icon icon-articles"
```

Following is the code of delete.js.haml to delete comments through ajax:

```
$("#comment_#{@comment.id}").fadeOut().remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also and change value at `delete.js.haml`

```
$("#commentsize").find("a").find("span").html("<%= @current_user.reload.comment_size %>");
```

Comment: Hey ck3g i tried ur solution bt its showing line from my sidebar file i.e <%= @current_user.reload.comment_size >Comments

Comment: oh. what if you rename this view to `delete.js.erb`?

Comment: if i rename it destroy.js.erb my delete is also not working.After refreshing comment gets deleted

Comment: can you put `console.log` or smth to be sure view running?

Comment: thanks ck3g for ur help..ur solution worked...jst need to make few changes as follows : $("#commentsize").find("a").find("span").html("#{ @current_user.reload.comments.size }");